# Problems with point to point streaming using FFmpeg

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, streaming, rtp

I want to live stream video from webcam and sound from microphone from one computer to another but there is some problems.

When I use this command line:

```
ffmpeg.exe -f dshow -rtbufsize 500M -i video="Camera":audio="Microphone" -c:v mpeg4 -c:a mp2 -f mpegts udp://127.0.0.1:1234
```

FFmpeg console starts filling with yellow color messages and stream becomes unstable: http://s16.postimg.org/qglcgr345/Untitled.png

To solve this problem I have added new parameter to the command line to set the frame rate -r 25:

```
ffmpeg.exe -f dshow -rtbufsize 500M -r 25 -i video="Camera":audio="Microphone" -c:v mpeg4 -c:a mp2 -f mpegts udp://127.0.0.1:1234
```

After I added -r 25 problem with yellow color messages disappears but then appears another problem. When I fresh start FFmpeg with this command line video and sound looks synchronous but after one or two minutes appears ~25 seconds lag between video and sound, sound goes behind video. I have tried that with different protocols UDP, TCP, RTP but problems are the same. Please help me!

Answer (score 2):

I found answer for my problem with "-r" and asynchronous audio and video. Who is interested answer is here: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/DirectShow (in paragraph "Specifying input framerate").